# jquery function check if radio button checked of not

Tags: php, jquery

I have three radio buttons based on database and a next button, I want my next button to work only if any one of the radio button is selected. My coding is shown below:

```
<?php
    $query ="select * from catagory";
    $rs = ec($query);
    $count = mysql_num_rows($rs);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
    {
        $id=$row['catagoryID'];
        echo "<input class='abcd' id='rb1' type='radio' name='catagory[]' value='$id'>".$row['catagory']."</option><br />";
    }
?>

<div class="next">Next</div>

<div id="div1">Some Code</div>
<div id="div2">Some Code</div>
```

---

My jQuery is like this:

```
$(function() { 
    $('#div1').hide(); 
    $('#div2').hide();

    $('.next').click(function(e) {
        $(this).slideUp("slow"); 
        $('#div1').slideDown("slow"); 
    });
 });
```

Comment: You have an error in your html code. You should replace "</option>" with "</input>"

Comment: inputs are self-closing.  He needs to just remove the option closer.  not that it matters really

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function () {
    $('#div1').hide();
    $('#div2').hide();
    $('.next').click(function (e) {
        if (!$('input[name="catagory[]"]').is(':checked')) {
            return
        }
        $(this).slideUp("slow");
        $('#div1').slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: I prefer to disable the button if it does nothing when you click!

Comment: then add `$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');` just before `return`